# How to resolve circular progress bar issue in angular js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html

I'am working a video tag in angular and HTML5 I can control the timer and tab in HTML5 Now I want to control the circular bar timer in angular js when I click the new tab the circular tab should not move even I mute the sound it should not run.

HTML

```
 <circular-progress id="timer_label" value="value" max="max" iterations="{{iteration}}" animation="{{animation}}" label="{{label}}" ng-click="acceptOrder()"></circular-progress>

<video autoplay onplay="clickplayer()" style="width: 100%;" id="player" ng-style="{ 'width' : width, 'height':height}" onended="endplayer()" fullscreen="true" controls  ng-src="{{videoSource | trustUrl }}" onvolumechange="myFunction()"  ontimeupdate="document.getElementById('tracktime').innerHTML = Math.floor(this.currentTime) + ' / ' + Math.floor(this.duration);"></video>
```

Angular JS code

`controller`

```
    var vm = this,timeout;
    vm.value = 0;
    vm.max = ($rootScope.durationSize);
    vm.animation = "linearEase";
    vm.iterations = 60; // Accelerate animation to fit the 1 second timeout function
    vm.label = "";
    var disp = vm.max;
    vm.start = function() {
        vm.label = disp;
        timeout = $timeout(function() {
            disp = disp-1;
            vm.value++;

                if(disp == 0){
                    //console.log(disp);
                    userService.closeCampaign(userId, cid , hIPaddress, browserInfo ,function(response){
                        console.log(response);
                        if(response.status == "success"){
                            console.log($rootScope.videoSource);
                            if($scope.res.campaigns.type=="appdownload"){
                            // if($scope.res.campaigns.type=="link" || $scope.res.campaigns.type=="appdownload"){ //cutDown to open new window as empty after click the open link option
                                $rootScope.redirectlink($scope.res.campaigns.link);
                            }
                            $window.location.reload();
                        }
                        else{
                            console.log('error redirect poster');
                            $window.location.reload();
                        }
                    });      
                }
            vm.start();
        }, 1000);
    };

    vm.acceptOrder = function() {
        $interval.cancel(disp);
        // disp = vm.max - vm.value;
        disp = null;
    }


    vm.start();
```